# Passagem por referêcia de uma estrutura com vetor em C!

Tags: c, ponteiro, estrutura-de-dados

Tenho o seguinte codigo:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    #define TAM 3

    typedef struct{
       char nome[50];
       char musica[50];
       int integrantes;
       int ranking;
    }Banda[TAM];

    void ler(Banda *banda){
       int i=0;
       for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
           printf("Nome da banda: ");
           fgets(banda[i]->nome,50,stdin);
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Tipo de musica: ");
           fgets(banda[i]->musica,50,stdin);
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Numero de integrantes: ");
           scanf("%i",&banda[i]->integrantes);
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("Posicao: ");
           scanf("%i",&banda[i]->ranking);
           fflush(stdin);
           printf("\n\n");
       }
    }

void mostrar(Banda banda){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        printf("Banda %i\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Nome da banda: %s\n",banda[i].nome);
        printf("Tipo de musica: %s\n",banda[i].musica);
        printf("Integrantes: %i\n",banda[i].integrantes);
        printf("Posicao: %i\n",banda[i].ranking);
    }
}

int main(){
   Banda banda[TAM];
   ler(&banda);
   mostrar(banda);
   return 0;
}
```

Consigo ler as 3 posições com a função `ler()`, porém na hora de escrever com a função `mostrar()`, só a primeira posição é escrita da maneira correta, as outras duas não,(aparecem letras e números aleatórios).

Agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

A declaração da struct não precisa de um tamanho, como está instanciando um vetor de struct no main, ou métodos ler e escrever devem receber vetores (ponteiros), quando pegar a posição de um vetor/ponteiro, não se usa mais `->` e sim `.`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define TAM 3

typedef struct{
    char nome[50];
    char musica[50];
    int integrantes;
    int ranking;
}Banda;//////////////////////////

/////////////////
void ler(Banda banda[]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        printf("Nome da banda: ");
        scanf("\n%50[^\n]",banda[i].nome);
        printf("Tipo de musica: ");
        scanf("\n%50[^\n]",banda[i].musica);
        printf("Numero de integrantes: ");
        scanf("%i",&banda[i].integrantes);////////
        printf("Posicao: ");
        scanf("%i",&banda[i].ranking);///////
        printf("\n\n");
    }
}

////////////////////////
void mostrar(Banda banda[]){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<TAM;i++){
        printf("Banda %i\n\n",i+1);
        printf("Nome da banda: %s\n",banda[i].nome);
        printf("Tipo de musica: %s\n",banda[i].musica);
        printf("Integrantes: %i\n",banda[i].integrantes);
        printf("Posicao: %i\n",banda[i].ranking);
    }
}

int main(){
    Banda banda[TAM];
    /////////////////
    ler(banda);
    mostrar(banda);
    return 0;
}
```

Deixei uma marca nos lugares onde fiz a correção.

Comment: Este código não funciona http://ideone.com/v51JKC

Comment: eu rodei antes de enviar... O que não funciona? não compila ou da algum erro?

Comment: Está executando aí, é só olhar.

Comment: alterei os métodos de entrada, agora está funcionando, tente evitar usar scanf com gets.